# How to use Geometry Nodes on vertices with rotation?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How would I distribute geometry following the rotation of the source mesh, but keep the distribution on the vertices (not random)?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

actually i found solution it was blender 2.93 alpha with this nodes

Comment: Oh, I see... and you also used vertex_normal as attribute. I've watched tutorials where they only talked about attributes like location (or position?), rotation, scale, normal etc. without the "vertex" at the beginning. Maybe that's the mistake and it already works in 2.92? Have to test it tomorrow.

Comment: Checked the attribute vertex_normal in 2.92 but it's not working... so it looks like it's new in 2.93.